# Send multiselect via POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

this is my view:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" asp-action="SaveLocationAndOrder">

    <select name="plates[]" multiple size="15" class="form-control">
        <option value="value1">Blubb</option>
         ...
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

My controller:

```
 public IActionResult SaveLocationAndOrder(string[] plates)
        {
            string string1 = plates[0];
            return View("myView");
        }
```

How can i receive the data in my controller? I can see that there are 2 objects are being sent but i cannot figure out how to get the strings in the controller. This is what the data looks like:

[image]

Comment: Try to set name attribute of your <select> tag to "plates" without "[]", like this `name="plates"`.

Comment: When I do that and i change the signature of the method to object[] plates, I don't receive any values: {object[0]}. 

When i switch to string[] plates, i receive two strings: "[object Object]"

Comment: i tried your code, it gives me ``value1`` in the controller

Comment: Have you tried multiple selected items?

Answer (score 0):

Ah ok, I figured out that the problem was in my view. I generated the  based on database entries and during the generation, the wrong value was set for every option:

Blah